# ggplot2 bar charts - how to specify x-axis positions of bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is my code, but I want a gap between the "overall" bar and the other two bars. How do I specify the x-axis positions of the bars?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group = factor(c("overall", "low-income", "high-income"), 
                              levels = c("overall", "low-income", "high-income")), 
                 AUC = c(0.70, 0.60, 0.80))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x=group, y=AUC)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

[image: current bar chart]

Answer (score 3):

Add a column between "overall" and "low-income." Give that column a value of 0 and a blank label.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group = factor(c("overall", " ", "low-income", "high-income"), 
                                levels = c("overall", " ","low-income", "high-income")), 
                 AUC = c(0.70, 0, 0.60, 0.80))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x=group, y=AUC)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: That's a nice one!

Answer (score 3):

Another option similar to **@G.Belton**, but you don't need to change your data. Use `scale_x_discrete` to exchange or add bar levels.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y = AUC)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("overall", "", "low-income", "high-income")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! This even allows me to drop the factor() specification to get the order I want. Awesome.